# Automatically Transcode Video and Upload to Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-attached-storage, video, encoding

I asked this over on superuser, with no luck - I'm hoping serverfault is the more appropriate site.

I'm looking for a solution to take video files from my HD Camera and automate transcoding to a smaller format and then uploading to the cloud (AWS or otherwise).

The ideal workflow would be where I have a NAS or a folder where I could simply drag the raw files from the camera (call it /toEncode ?). The NAS/computer would see new files there and automatically transcode the video to settings I have already picked and save them to a folder (/readyToUpload) that is sync'd with AWS S3 or some other cloud storage system.

I know that freenas and such will do somehting similar for xbox360 and ps3 transcoding - can I tap into this for my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really does depend on what formats you want to ingest and transcode to/from but certainly any Mac will happily let you create that kind of chain of work. You'd just create a small automator app or applescript and link it to a watch-folder, which would do the work and drop it wherever you like, it could do the upload too if you wished. I'm sure you could write something similar in powershell or a bash script too but I know for a fact it'll work on a Mac.

Comment: Interesting - I've never used automator, but I'll have a look! Thanks for the solution. Would love to know if this would be possible on a freenas box or a similar linux box (I'm sure it is...I just don't know the process).

Comment: You're really getting more into Superuser.com territory there.

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the computer. A NAS is generally a basic linux host so you could use a scripted workflow with the aid of a few command line tools. ie.

fsniper (folder watching tool)
ffmpeg (swiss army knife of video transcoding tools)
s3fs  (Fuse based S3 filesystem)

a script in your favourite language would be activated by new files identified by fsniper, it would pass them one at a time to ffmpeg with your preferred transcoding option and then write the output to an interim directory and then move the file using normal file commands to the s3 mounted filesystem.

This should give you the expected workflow above.

M.